# Как выгрузить из Heroku базу данных?

Tags: python, python-3.x, хостинг, heroku

Хостил на Heroku приложение и за некоторое время оно собрала базу нужных данных, но как мне теперь выгрузить эту БД с Heroku?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавил в код приложения функцию отправляющую файл базы данных мне на почту. Проблема решена.